# Does rating a match have any effect on future matchmaking?

Tags: overwatch

At the top of the post-game recap are a trio of radio buttons asking me to rate the match I just played. Does this rating exist only so Blizzard can run analytics at some future point, or does it have any effect on the matchmaking system (for example, encouraging a team shuffle or causing the servers to find a new game)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> New "Rate This Match" and "Rate This Player" options have been added to the end-of-round flow
>   Rate This Match: These ratings are designed to provide the Overwatch development team with feedback about how much you enjoyed a match. This data will be used over time to improve matchmaking and the game in general.
>   Rate This Player: Positive and negative ratings can have an effect on how likely players are to be matched with one another in future games.

[source](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/19891059515)